# WPF override a text on canvas + zooming dont work well

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, drawing

**Problem 1**

How can I override a written text without delete the whole canvas content?
Can I do that over `C#`? Without adding elements in the `XAML` code?

**Problem 2**

I intergrated a zoom function but it zooms only if I'm pointing on something drawn in my canvas. How can I just zoom when I'm just pointing on my `Canvas`?

`XAML`

```
<Canvas x:Name="coordinateSystemBackground" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Cross" MouseWheel="coordinateSystemBackground_MouseWheel" RenderTransformOrigin="0.688,0.559" Width="1200" Height="720">
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="1200" Height="750">
        <Canvas x:Name="coordinateSystem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Cross" UseLayoutRounding="False" Canvas.Left="0" Width="1200" Height="720">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="st"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Canvas>
```

`My Zoom function`

```
private void coordinateSystemBackground_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    // Skalierungsfaktor   
    double ScaleRate = 1.1;

    //Transformiert gesamte Canvas...  
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        st.ScaleX *= ScaleRate;
        st.ScaleY *= ScaleRate;
        labZoomFaktor.Content = (int)((st.ScaleX * 100) - 100) + " %";
    }
    else
    {
        st.ScaleX /= ScaleRate;
        st.ScaleY /= ScaleRate;
        labZoomFaktor.Content = (int)((st.ScaleX * 100) - 100) + " %";
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for hit testing to pick up mouse input there needs to be some non-null part of the targeted element under the cursor. In this case the canvas's children are picking up events and bubbling them to the `Canvas` but the `Canvas` itself is just empty space and so won't pick up the mouse input. By setting `Background="Transparent"` on the `Canvas` you will make the entire thing visible to hit testing.